# Why must I run bundle exec jekyll serve after changing _includes to see changes?

Tags: jekyll

I have a navigation.html file inside the folder _includes.

After I make any change to this file and reload the page at http://localhost:4000/, I don't see any changes.

But if I go to the terminal, stop serving and then use `bundle exec jekyll serve` again, the changes are displayed on the browser.

The same does not happen if, for example, I make a change to a post, my index.md or _config.yml. Changes made to these files appear when I reload the browser.

Why does it happen? Is there a way I can fix it?

Note: I'm using the theme `jekyll-theme-hacker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Jekyll reloader` is only triggered by markdown changes. For changes to `html` or `config` you have to follow the `_turn in off` and `on_` procedure.